# AVAudioSession.sharedInstance is not called

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a audio app and I would like the audio to keep playing When the screen is off.(It works well in the back ground while the screen is on.)

Background mode is enabled on xcode(I set "audio" value in Info.plist.) and I implemented "AVAudioSession.sharedInstance" however the application crashes when the screen goes off in my device. Any idea to solve this issue?

Here is the full code

```
var player:AVAudioPlayer!

        init(withStartingClosure block1:@escaping(_ dict:[String:Any],_ index:Int) -> Void,andStopingClosure block2:@escaping(_ index:Int) -> Void,finishedAllClosure block3:((_ finished:Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
            self.didStartPlaying = block1
            self.didStopPlaying = block2
            self.didFinishPlaying = block3
        }
        deinit {
            self.mode = .stopped
        }
    }
    extension AudioPlayer {
        func getURL(ofAudio name:String) -> URL {
            let url = URL(string: name)!
            let nm = url.deletingPathExtension().absoluteString
            let type = url.pathExtension
            let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: nm, withExtension: type)!
            return path
        }

        func setupPlayer(withData data:[String:Any]){
            let name = data["audio"] as! String
            var idx = self.currentIndex - 1
            if idx < -1 {
                idx = -1
            }
            print("\nCurrentIndex = \(idx),and Audio is = \(data)")
            let path = self.getURL(ofAudio: name)
            do {
                try self.setupAudioSession()
                self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path)
                self.player.delegate = self
                if self.player.prepareToPlay() == true {
                    self.player.play()
                    self.didStartPlaying?(data, idx)
                }else{
                    print("----------Can't Play \(data)")
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error!", message: error.localizedDescription, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()
            }

         let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    } catch  {
        fatalError("error1")
    }

    do {
        try session.setActive(true)
    } catch {

        fatalError("sessionError")
    }

        }
```

The error I receive.
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]

```
func reloadCell(AtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath,shouldStop value:Int = 0){
    //"value" is default value.
    // if it is 1. it means stop playing animation of this TableViewCell
    let cell = self.table.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath, shouldStop: value)

   //This is the code which get crash
    self.table.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: What line is it crashing on? Can you trim the source code to a minimum?

Comment: Yes I minimized the code.

Comment: Given the crash, it has nothing to do with the code you have posted. It is related to your UI and a UITableView. In Xcode, go to the Breakpoints Navigator (Command-7) and set an exception breakpoint using the + in the bottom left corner. Then Xcode will break when the problem occurs rather than later on.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I receive the error in another viewController.  Do you have any idea why it get crash?

Comment: When it crashes, you need to look at the indexPath passed into `reloadCell` and try to work out why it is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

NSRangeException. It means you are calling a cell - Indexpath that doesn't exist in the table view.